# Connecting client to JBoss cluster

Tags: windows-xp, cluster, jboss

I am new to JBoss. Basically I have managed to cluster 2 nodes with:

Node 1: run.bat -c all -g DefaultPartition –u 230.0.0.4 -b 10.67.51.28 -Djboss.messaging.ServerPeerID=1

Node 2: run.bat -c all -g DefaultPartition –u 230.0.0.4 -b 10.67.50.21 -Djboss.messaging.ServerPeerID=2

I know that if i cofigure a Apache load balancing(Mod_JK) to sit infront of the cluster, the client simply just punch in the IP of the Apache, and Apache will redirect the traffic to the nodes.

But I do not want to have a Apache infront of the cluster. So how do my client access the cluster?? Do i need to configure something in JBoss, or isit a MUST to have a load balancer for the client to access the cluster??

MANY thanks in advance....

Comment: what did you end up doing?

Answer (score 0):

you could use roud robin DNS balancing. It's not the most beautiful solution and you will loose transparent failover even if your apps can distribute state. On the other hand, if you're desperate not to use Apache...

Comment: Hi, actually the objective i am trying to achieved here is to just perfrom a simply failover (not really interested in load balancing). My boss basically just wants to prove that JBoss clustering is able to perform failover. So i did a failover with mod_jk. But she is not favour of having a load balancer infront of the JBoss. Any advice for me on how to go about doing??

Comment: Hi Nivek, if you want to have 2 separate JBoss instances up and running you also need 2 separate IP addresses per node and some means to route your client requests. Maybe your boss is concerned that the SPOF is now in the LB itself. You need to address this with some Active/Stand-by configuration; on its own, no App Server can do transparent failover

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what OS you're on, but if it's Linux then [Linux Virtual Server](http://www.linuxvirtualserver.org/) is designed to load-balance arbitrary network-based applications.

Comment: Hi, I am trying this out on Windows XP Pro... Actually the objective i am trying to achieved here is to just perfrom a simply failover (not really interested in load balancing). My boss basically just wants to prove that JBoss clustering is able to perform failover. So i did a failover with mod_jk. But she is not favour of having a load balancer infront of the JBoss. Any advice for me on how to go about doing??

Comment: Fair enough, then I'm retagging your question; I can't advise on Windows as I don't use proprietary software so have no idea of the toolset you have available.  If you change your mind and want to use Linux, remove the tag and let me know; the appropriate tool for failover under Linux would be Linux-HA, at http://www.linux-ha.org/wiki/Main_Page .